# Page indicator on adapterviewflipper

Tags: android-adapterview

How to add page indicator on adpterviewflipper for my widget's home page?

Answer (score 0):

Not much to go on but where you create the layout for each page you can set a Textview to have the value of the position of view as an indicator.

e.g. in you Adapter Class

```java
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.page, parent, false);
    TextView pageText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pageText);
    pageText.setText(String.valueOf(position));

....
```

(This assumes you have `TextView` in the right place in the xml layout file you are using for the page template, or you could add the `TextView` programmatically instead)

You can as I do use `getItem(position)` to then query the object to get a value to use as a page indicator/title